# how to refresh UI in c# windows application at change of tab in taskbar

Tags: c#, user-interface, refresh

how to refresh UI in c# windows application at change of tab in task-bar when it is in long process or at-least where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do the long process asynchronously (i.e. in a separate thread). This keeps the GUI thread free to draw the interface.

For example, take a look at the [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and the examples at the bottom of that MSDN page. It will allow you to execute a task on the background.